# Cassandra slow reads (by partition key) for large data rows fetched

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, scylla

I have a 5 node cassandra (3.11) cluster on AWS.
Machine specs

```
Model   vCPU    Memory (GiB)    Instance Storage (GB)   Networking Bandwidth (Gbps)
i3.large    2   15.25   1 x 475 NVMe SSD    Up to 10
```

For my keyspace the replication factor = 2.

I need to store the movement records for vehicles in a table.

**The columns are pretty straight-forward - vehicleId, lat, lng, timestamp**

We have 100K vehicles and have historical 10 years of data of each.

The total volume of data is around 2 billion rows.

**I need to read all the data for the given vehicle in ASC order to do some processing on it.**

Earlier our table structure was

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle_movement (
vehicle_id int,
timestamp timestamp,
lat double,
lng double,
PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_id, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC)

Where vehicle_id was PARTITION KEY. 
AND the query was

SELECT lat, lng, timestamp from vehicle_movement where vehicle_id = xyz
```

The performance of read query was quite slow (~5 sec). We found that since each vehicle_id alone as partition key wont suffice as we have 300K+ records per vehicle and this may result in large partitions.

So we changed our schema a bit

Following is my updated table

```
    CREATE TABLE vehicle_movement (
    vehicle_id int,
    year int,
    timestamp timestamp,
    lat double,
    lng double,
    PRIMARY KEY ((vehicle_id, year), timestamp)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC)

    Here vehicle_id and year are composite partition keys 
which ensures that each partition may not contain more than 10k-15k records.
```

But since my problem statement remains the same - fetch all records for a given vehicle in ASC order,
I further split the query into multiple

```
Eg
SELECT lat, lng, timestamp from vehicle_movement where vehicle_id = xyz and year IN (2018, 2019)


SELECT lat, lng, timestamp from vehicle_movement where vehicle_id = xyz and year IN (2020, 2021)

SELECT lat, lng, timestamp from vehicle_movement where vehicle_id = xyz and year IN (2022, 2023)
```

This approach reduced latency as compared to earlier but still it's not satisfactory (2 to 2.5 sec as compared to earlier 5 sec).

**My client is spring based java app wherein I use spring-data-cassandra.**

I execute these multiple queries and accumulate all the results.

**For my reads, I have used consistency = LOCAL_ONE (which is fastest for reads)**

I tried serial as well as parallel execution of the queries but still overall latency is more of less the same.

So my queries are:

1. What can be done to improve the latency further - I have to read all the data of given vehicle order by timestamp ASC to do processing?
2. Is cassandra even the right choice given I have high throughput reads?
3. I even gave SCYLLA DB a go as it is a drop-in replacement for cassandra with better benchmarks. SCYLLA gave me improved latency by around 30%

EDIT 2

I de-normalized my schema a bit and it have improved my read latencies significantly.

```
CREATE TYPE movement_point (
     lat DOUBLE,
     lng DOUBLE,
     ts TIMESTAMP
 );
 
  CREATE TABLE vehicle_movement_denorm (
      vehicle_id INT,
      year INT,
      points LIST<FROZEN<movement_point>>, // stored in ASC order
      count INT, // As there is no built in function for count
      PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_id, year)
  ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (year ASC);
```

**Fortunately for each vehicle and year, we have 7000-8000 records, which are fitting nicely into frozen list whilst maintaining order.**

While reading data, Im querying for 3-4 years in a single call.
So 2-3 calls to fetch my data.

```
SELECT points from vehicle_movement_denorm where vehicle_id = xyz and year in (2020, 2021, 2022) 

SELECT points from vehicle_movement_denorm where vehicle_id = xyz and year in (2023, 2024)
```

This approach is giving me read latencies of 200-400 millis which is quite good.
Is this denormalization approach good and scalable?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes - if you have a list which is fairly short (7000 records isn't short, but it's in the reasonable ballpark. If it can grow larger or even be unlimited, you'll have big problems) and that you never need to modify - just read old historic value, then a frozen list is indeed a good choice.

Though I am surprised that using a frozen list instead of a partition reduced latency so much. Reading contiguous, sorted, data from a partition shouldn't have been that much slower than reading a frozen list. Maybe for some reason the original read did paging a lot more, and you had small pages and/or your network has high latency (?) which caused paging to be slower?

In principle, the best way to get low **latency** is to make the problem more parallelized, not less. In your latest solution, you are reading all the data from a single partition, and therefore a single node (or at most, 3 nodes). In ScyllaDB, it's even worse - just 1 or 3 CPUs out of the cluster's 10 CPUs. I think you'll get even lower latency if make (vehicle_id, year) a compound partition key (year will be part of the partition key, not clustering key) and you'll do all the SELECTs for different years in parallel. Each of those will be sent to a different CPU, utilize more of the cluster's processing power, and finish faster (lower latency).

Comment: Thanks...will definitely give it a try

Comment: I gave it a try but latency of this approach is always on higher side.
Executing queries parallely by delegating to java ExecutorService actually had higher latency than that using serial query (get records of 3 years in 1 query followed by other )
Maybe Im missing some key cassandra config which is resulting in high latency